# converting nanoseconds to seconds and nanoseconds

Tags: c++, time, integer-arithmetic

I have a very large nanosecond value (representing nanoseconds since epoch) which I try to break down into seconds since epoch and nanoseconds like this:

```
uint64_t nanosecondsEpoch;
unsigned secs = nanosecondsEpoch / 1000000000ULL;
unsigned nanos = nanosecondsEpoch - (secs * 1000000000ULL);
```

the problem is if I try to stitch it back together like this:

```
uint64_t stichBack = secs * 1000000000ULL + nanos
```

I get something which is way off. I think the reason is that when I perform the division, I get 1357314854.03 for secs and the 0.03 gets dropped (causing the big discrepancy)..but I'm confused because it feels like I should be able to save both pieces of information in an unsigned and recover the information without resorting to floats? Am I doing something plain silly in the arithmetic that I can't seem to catch?

Here is a specific example:

value for nanoseconds since epoch somtime today in the morning: 1357314854032484000

I would use uint64_t if i could for both seconds and nanosecond unsigned, but what I'm wondering is why I can't break the above value as above and put it back together.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example for which the final result is wrong?

Comment: FWIW, this is now a solved problem in the standard library (`<chrono>`) or in Boost (Boost.Chrono) for older compilers.

Comment: Why don't you use modulo 1000000000 instead of nano - (secs*10..)?

Comment: Have you tried using `uint64_t` for secs and nanos instead of `unsigned`? Does the problem persist then?

Comment: A 32 bit integer is large enough to hold a range of approx. 136 years in seconds. Do your values fall outside this range? Are you maybe using `SYSTEMTIME` in Windows instead which represents the number of 100-nanosecond ticks since 1 January 1601 00:00:00 UT?

Comment: Your example looks fine to me: http://ideone.com/wqsWwf.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - interesting, it seems like if I omit the ULL it doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `1e9` is less than `2^32-1` (maximum unsigned 32-bit integer), if the original value is large enough, the quotient may still be too large to fit in a 32-bit integer. Not sure what your original value is, but it's possible you're truncating your `secs` value as a result.

Comment: The original value im working with is 1357314854032484000 which is sometime around today at 9am in nanoseconds since epoch.